# MapReduce to analyse the product sale in given time period for the day

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i have a log data  for a particular  product sale  as below

```
   product     date              time   Rs
   red ballons 2012-10-02       0128    1000
   blue socks  2012-10-02       0003    3498
   current     2012-10-02       0120    0987
   red ballons 2012-10-02       0056    1000
   blue socks   2012-10-02      0059    6764
```

Could some one please give me suggestion as how to write the `java mapreduce` to calculate the
 product sale per hour and for per 12 hour for a particular day 
i am new to `mapreduce` .  i need to understand 
how mapper should choose its key and how a single map reduce job will give both the analysis for one hour sale and for 12 hours sale
 any help will take my thought further thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your mapper determine one or more time component (date and hour, date and 12 hours, etc.) for each entry, and come up with a unique identifier for them.  Use the unique identifier as your key and each product sale amount as your value when you write with your mapper.

Your reducers will receive all the sales for each of your periods.  All you need to do is run a sum over all the amounts.

Suppose you want to do multiple time periods, take 1 and 12 hour periods. I'd create a stripHours function such as this one.

```
public static Date stripHours(Date date, int hours) {
    long offsetMillis = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000l;
    long timePeriod = hours * 3600000l;
    return new Date(((date.getTime() - offsetMillis) / timePeriod) * timePeriod + offsetMillis);
}
```

For each row input to your mapper, write a row with key=stripHours(date, 1) and another row with key=stripHours(date, 12).  In both instances, make the value the product sale amount.

Of course, you'll need some way to distinguish between keys of type 1 hour and keys of type 12 hour.  A really simple way would be to use some kind of string concatenation such as "12 " + strippedDate.getTime() and "1 " + strippedDate.getTime(), but I'm sure you can figure out the details.

Comment: thanks . so if i choose product and date(not time) as a key then reducer can aggregate over the sale for a date in total, is there a way in this case as reducer can write output for both for hour and for 12 hours . do we need to write two mapreduce i mean one for hour calculation and one for 12 hour sale calculation. if this is true then in this case for per hour calculation like 1am to 2pm then 2pm to 3pm we need to write two mapreduce job, going with this approach i need to write 24 mapreduce jobs . i think this is not correct way .

Comment: I'll edit above and elaborate, but you can definitely do it in a single job.

Comment: based on  above explanation . can we have mapper who produces multilple   types of keys like above one hour and 12 hour ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea I was trying to get across.  Good luck!